# org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ui.Model]: Specified class is an interface

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring boot. My dao implementation is :

```
public void saveDetails(Proforma_Invoice proforma) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(proforma);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen())
            session.flush();
        if (session != null && session.isOpen())
            session.close();
    }
}
```

My controller is :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/enquiry", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEnquiryScreen(Model model, Item_entity item, Integer item_code, vendor_entity vendor) {
        System.out.println("Controller is starting..");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("enquiry_Screen");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/enquiry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView demo(@ModelAttribute("enquiry") Model model, Item_entity item, Integer item_code,
            vendor_entity vendor, Proforma_Invoice proforma) {
        System.out.println("Controller is starting..");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("enquiry_Screen"););
        return mav;
    }
```

Using these when i saving data then i got error :

```
2019-03-12 09:45:34.352 ERROR 7256 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ui.Model]: Specified class is an interface] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ui.Model]: Specified class is an interface
```

Please see the issue. and help me to solve the issue.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your DAO (using obsolete Hibernate interfaces, manually attempting to manage sessions and transactions)--use JPA or (best of all) Spring Data repositories to create all of that code for you. Also review and use Java naming conventions, such as `Item` (or `ItemEntity`, if you must), not `Item_entity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to mix using a `Model` as a controller parameter and using `@ModelAttribute`. `@ModelAttribute` is used when you have a form object that contains parameters from the incoming request and you want Spring to copy those parameters into an instance of the object. Either use a form object for your POST mapping (a good idea) or drop the annotation to use `Model`.